# How much force would be required to lift a 200KG contraption/machine+human vertically 3-5 feet and keep them hovering in position?

Tags: aerodynamics, propulsion

A friend an I are designing what could be described as a hovercraft(bike). We have a basic idea of what we want to do in regards to design,  but we can't start assembling it until we know the forces required to A) Lift upwards of 200KG (Human + Safety Aspects + Mechanical Parts eg. Engine, Fans providing thrust), B) The amount of force required to propel the occupant + machine (safely) forward and C) The amount of thrust to keep the device steady and level at the give height (3-5 feet).

The design right now has 'fans' and the 'propulsion systems' (for lack of better word) at the front and back. The (bike's) length is undecided as well. 4, 5 and 6 feet long are the 'standard lengths' we have decided to test on. I know this is not that much eligible/confirmed information to work with, but Ryan and I have no grasp for physics.

Comment: You'd need 200kg of force to lift 200kg of weight.

Comment: Anything beyond the simple answer of $F=mg$ is likely to be off-topic on this site; [engineering questions are out of our scope](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site).

Comment: You know the weight? That's the force. If you have no grasp of physics, get one.

Answer (score 1):

A) and C) are pretty similar, you'll need 200kg equivalent in lift (should be around 2000N of force) to hover your bike. Anymore and you'll start to accelerate upwards, with the equation

F=ma,

force F mass m and acceleration a. Remember if you're moving up or down you'll need to include the weight of your craft in your calculations. For example if you have an upwards force of 2500N your craft will accelerate upwards at

(2500N-2000N)/200kg = 2.5m/s²

Same goes with B), but this time you don't need to include the weight(don't confuse it with mass!)

250N/200kg = 5m/s²

Comment: You very soon stop accelerating and will travel upwards with a constant velocity, due to reduction of the angle of attack of the fan blades and to aerodynamic drag force on the shape of the body.

Comment: @Koyovis and then you will start accelerating again because of the reduction of aerodynamic force and reduction in gravitational force. Op can reach remarkable heights!

Comment: No you won't. When helicopter pilots pull on their collective they accelerate upwards for about a second, then the helicopter claims up with a constant climb speed.